# how come a http://localhost:8080 given in browser directed to tomcat intallation folder(to public root dictory)

Tags: url, tomcat, browser

```
when i started tomcat container i am curious when we given `http://localhost:8080` in browser.
```

how come it is directed to tomcat installation folder to its public root directory. say to C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\webapps\ROOT

. here localhost is the server name. how can browser find a server running in my PC? when i run web container is it registering some where so that my browser will see its public directory?some how tomcat is registering as a server with name `localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

localhost is a special network name that translates to IP address 127.0.0.1.  That is a loop-back address.

Tomcat opens port 8080 and listens on it for connections.  Telling the browser to open `http://localhost:8080` causes it to open that port on the local system.

As for showing the ROOT directory, I'm not sure about Tomcat's default home page, but it seems reasonable that is it.

Comment: It means any request to localhost i.e 127.0.0.1 bypass local network interface hardware. and it routes to tomcat and how  127.0.0.1 ip address is configured to tomcat application(even though is is named as web server, its an application right i.e another coded program)?i want to know how it is implemented. i think it relates to networking.

Comment: All 127.0.0.1 network traffic is looped-back to the same server.  So, all tomcat has to do is open port 8080 and listen on it, then any process on the same server can access it using localhost, or 127.0.0.1.  Ports are global to the server; only one process can have a specific port open at a time.

Comment: yes i understood all traffic(say requests) loops back to server present in the system where request is genereted. now this ip address 127.0.0.1 is pointing tomcat application(a webserver,i know). see here is flow browser-->loopback address(127.0.0.1)-->routes to local server.
how localserver is pointed to the one we installed, where can i see those configurations.

Comment: Ah, I think a good tcp/ip primer is what you need.  You want to know how localhost access is going to the tomcat process, right?  Well, there are two addressing parts to connecting to a tcp/ip service - the IP address, which identifies the machine (actually one interface on the machine) and the port, which identifies the listening process, if any.  Tomcat defaults to port 8080 and opens it, probably using the all-interface special address 0.0.0.0.  Any tcp/ip request to that server on port 8080 gets routed to tomcat.  Try `netstat -an | grep 8080`.

Comment: Also note that any process can open port 8080.

Comment: when tomcat starts it opens 8080 port nd ready to listen. when localhost with port 8080 is given it directs the request to tomcat root directory. can a port 3030 have same ip address? if yes then it belongs to another process(application/running service) right?
then generally we r giving a url like www.example.com in browser why not we specifying port there? how can a applicaition is associated with a port so that it listens
could you tell me where these configurations are present. like can we change localhost to a name we want. some part configuration might've assigned 127.0.0.1 to localhost.

Comment: there might be some place where our application is assigned to a certain port. its not like anything written in a notepad just like    localhost:8080=open tomcat. i know these includes how browser works, how internal network works and parts of networking knowledge. i am curious to know these details.

Comment: the command you have given is not working please give some other working command. i have win7

Comment: Ah, sorry about the command - it's a Unix/Linux command.  `netstat -an` will still work, but you'll have to find another way to search the output.  As for the port number, http://www.anywhere.com opens the default HTTP port, which is 80.  As for port configurations, the port is chosen by the application, so it's an application-specific configuration to change the port.  I would have to search tomcat docs to find where it is defined for Tomcat.  Yes, port 3030 can have the same IP address.

Comment: And for the name of the system, that's a little more complicated.  DNS is the most durable solution, but the hardest to learn and setup.  Most systems have a file which can be used to define name-to-ip-address mappings, but that would require editting that file on every system that will connect to this server - not likely what you want.  If your system is part of a work network, it probably already has a network name.  Otherwise, the IP address of the server can be used.  `ipconfig` can help to find the ip address.